# Python: Adding constant to iteration variable in for loop

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, iteration

Is there anyway I can add constant to the iteration variable when executing for loop?
This is what I am trying to achieve:

```py
for i += 100 in [9,2,7,4,1,8,3,5]:
  print(i)
```

Output should be:

```
109
102
107
104
101
108
103
105
```

I understand I can add constant right before printing. But was curious if there is anyway to add during iteration.

Comment: `for i in [100 + x for x in [9,2,7,4,1,8,3,5]]:` or `for i in [9,2,7,4,1,8,3,5]: i+= 100`

Comment: Can we use `numpy array`?

Comment: maybe you can use `numpy arrays`. `a=numpy.array([9,2,7,4,1,8,3,5]) for i in a+100: print(i)` will do the job.

Answer (score 2):

```
for i in [9,2,7,4,1,8,3,5]:
  print(i+100)
```

Answer (score 2):

No, but you can add a constant to each value just *before* it gets assigned to the iteration variable.

```
for i in (x + 100 for x in [9, 2, 7, 4, 1, 8, 3, 5])
    ...
```

You might also abuse a property, since a `for` loop performs assignments much like `=` does.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, incr):
        self.incr = incr

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self._x + self.incr

    @x.setter
    def x(self, v):
        self._x = v


i = A(200)
for i.x in [1,2,3]:
    print(i.x)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can start with assigning your data to a list item and then iterate through it as mentioned above. It will you in the future as you will start using constants or will need to change the data constantly. Or it would help you if you would have many lists and you can try to do it for all of them at the same time:

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
list2 = [5,4,3,2,1]

for i in list1:
    print(100 + i)

for i in list2:
    print(200+ i)
```